# Active class not working in javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I trying to make mobile menu, but it's showing error saying mobileMenu not defined.

`

```
  .ul_one{
        position: fixed;
        top: 58px;
        gap: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 100%;
        left: 100%;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .ul_one .active{
        left: 0;
    }
    .li{
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
```

```
let burger = document.querySelector(".menu_icon");
let menu = document.querySelector(".ul_one");

burger.addEventListener("click", function(){
    mobileMenu.classList.toggle("active");
})
```

`

Burger menu should pop out and it didn't worked out.

Comment: Based on the code you've provided `mobileMenu` is undefined, you need to define in like you did for `menu` and `burger`

Comment: Are the variables menu and mobileMenu actually referring to the same element?

Comment: you probably meant `menu`